# .net compiled expressions instead of activator.createinstance()

Tags: .net, lambda, activator, createinstance

I scan my assemblies looking for a specific types **typeof(MyInterface<>)**
I then add these types to a static dictionary so that I can create instances of these types when requested.

I am creating these types using Activator.CreateInstance. But then I noticed the bad performance and research pointed me to http://mattgabriel.co.uk/2016/02/12/215/

Now, what I do is, store the compiled lambda in the dictionary

```
static IDictionary<string, Delegate> Store = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Delegate>();
```

Where I am stuck is that when I get the delegate to create the instance by

```
Delegate instanceToCreate = DelegateStore.Store["keyName"];
```

Then I need to call the delegate which will create the instance by passing the parameter **_configuration** to the constructor. I tried;

```
instanceToCreate.DynamicInvoke(new object[] { _configuration });
```

The error I get is:

> Object of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot' cannot be converted to type 'System.Object[]'.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Probably `.Cast<object>().ToArray()` is necessary on your `_configuration` list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the "Delegate". Instead I used the concrete type;

```
_store = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Creator>();
```

this allowed me to just call the constructor as;

```
var createMe = store["creatorkey"]
createMe(param1,....)
```